# Is there a theme for any desktop environment that has a close button extending to the very edge of the titlebar?

Tags: themes

I am looking for a theme that has a big clickable area, about 40x40 pixels for the close button and there is no additional space below/above/aside the close button on the title bar.

This is something that would presumably help many people but I haven't found such a theme yet.

I can rule out openbox-3 themes because on that WM there is always a 1 px border around title bar buttons.

Comment: What is so bad about a 1 px border around buttons?

Comment: With Kubuntu, you can push the mouse pointer into the absolute top right corner of the screen when a window is maximized and click to close the window even though the mouse pointer is not positioned over the actual close button image. @Takkat, may something to do with Fitts' law: https://blog.codinghorror.com/fitts-law-and-infinite-width/ for example. So while there's nothing wrong with the border, from rhe perspective of usability, the mouse pointer would need to be positioned more carefully if the border isn't functional in the clickable sense.

Comment: @DKBose: is that what the OP meant?

Comment: @DKBose The animated gif is no longer available. You are spot on about Fitts' law; that additional 1px border violates Fitts' law.

Comment: @user800 I could make another gif but it appears that this question is abandoned. Plus not many people seem to care about Fitts' law! Even with Kubuntu, some themes don't allow what I described. The default Breeze theme is fine.